# Difference between cafeteria and lunchroom

Tags: meaning

Do these two words mean the same thing? I tried googling  but had no luck. I searched lunchroom in the wikipedia website, but it jumped to the page explaining the cafeteria.

Comment: In Google enter `define cafeteria`.  You will see listings for definitions in several dictionaries.  Prefer the Webster's and Oxford versions.  If you still don't understand, come back and ask your question again.

Comment: +1 for taking feedback on your last question in good faith and [using it to frame your subsequent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392182/difference-between-publicly-available-open-access-and-in-public-domain#comment926788_392182). Thank you, very sincerely, for that attitude. A cafeteria will necessarily *serve food* (paid or free); a lunchroom can be just a room in the workplace to sit down and eat your meal in. Often it's just a small unadorned room with a table, a fridge, a sink, supplies, etc, and people bring their own lunches in. But a cafeteria must provide food.

Comment: *Cafeteria* has a range of related meanings, so read all the definitions in a good dictionary. Some are synonymous with *lunch room* and some aren't

Comment: Googling tip: type `define lunchroom` and several dictionary definitions will be among the hits.  You have to scroll down past Google's mysteriously proposed selection to see them.  And there are several sites that collect a few different dictionary's definitions all on one page, e.g. thefreedictionary.com. // Another way you can compare similar words is in a thesaurus.  If you work with an online thesaurus, you can easily go back and forth to compare the two definitions.  An easy way to get started is to google `synonym lunchroom`.

Comment: Somewhat related at ELL.SE: *[What is the place in the office people grab coffee and snack?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24489)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DanBron said, you can bring food from home to both, but the key difference is that a cafeteria offers food (usually for sale).

Here's another distinction: When I'm talking with my son about the places in his middle school (grades 6 - 8), sometimes I need to be able to distinguish between two slightly different, but connected, places.

1. There's the place where he interacts with the servers and the cashier, and I call it *the cafeteria line* or *the lunch line*.
2. There's a bigger, open space with tables and chairs, where he interacts with the lunch monitors.  I call this *the lunchroom*.  I could call it *the cafeteria*, but then there could be some confusion, whether I mean the place where he sits and eats, or the place where he pushes his tray, selects what he's buying, and gives his ID for his account to be charged.

In a small company, *lunchroom* can be used as a synonym for *break room*.  It might have a refrigerator, cupboards, sink, a table or two, and possibly a sofa.  It might also have a vending machine.  This room would never be called a *cafeteria*.

Comment: Well, if I weren't a native speaker, I might be wondering, in regard to your last sentence, *Why wouldn't it be called a cafeteria, since it is "offering food (usually for sale)"  by means of vending machines?*

Comment: @Clare - When I said "offers food (usually for sale)" I meant human beings doing the offering.  Sorry I wasn't clear.